# Access 2013 Form TextBoxes with functions not calculating

Tags: vba, ms-access

I've created an Access database (orig.v2007, updated with v2010, and some users now use it with v2013), which my office has been using for the past two years, without this issue.  Recently this issue started happening: There is a form to enter data. The form's record source is a table, and it has a few text boxes where it has functions which lookup data from other tables. For only a few people in the office, the text boxes with the functions are not auto-populating. They also get, that have this problem are all using Access 2013, but not everyone using 2013 has this problem. I am still using 2010 and I cannot duplicate this problem.

The text box Control Source is `=GetSKU([Forms]![frmCP]![Project_Type])`in the status bar, a message that says "Calculate". (It seems like it's not auto-calculating.) When the user single-clicks on the text box, it populates with the text that it's supposed to. The users

The function is as follows:

```
Function GetSKU(PT As Long)
    Dim ptvar As Variant
    ptvar = DLookup("[SKU]", "[tblProjectType]", "[ProjType_ID] = " & PT)
    GetSKU = ptvar
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem this week with our Access databases. We recently upgraded from Access 2010 to 2013 and now any unbound text boxes that perform calculations (Iif, sum, average, dlookup, etc.) are empty until you either click in the textbox or hit F9.

[This discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1701369c-02b4-4f43-abe7-03b099b4d517/access-2010-form-fields-not-calculating-until-clicked?forum=accessdev) on MSDN may be helpful. It suggests that pressing F9 or restarting the computer will (temporarily) solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've got this issue popping up myself, now.  I have a workaround, but it's nasty, and no guarantee it plays well with your solution if there's complex form-handling going on.

```
Private Sub Form_Activate()

    Me.SetFocus
    SendKeys "{F9}"

End Sub
```